# rake / rails .save! not updating database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am trying to save changes to my database trough a rake task.

In my rake task I do something like:

```
namespace :parts do
  desc "Update Parts table, swap names in title"
  task :swap => :environment do
    Part.swap
  end
end
```

In my Part class I do

```
def self.swap
  Part.all.each do |part|
    if (part.title =~ REGEX) == 0
      part.title.gsub! REGEX, '\2 \1'
      puts part.title
      part.save!
    end
  end
end
```

However, this does not save the part. The `save!` does return true. the `puts part.title` does return the value I want.

If I call

```
Part.update(part.id, title: part.title)
```

The database updates properly. Why is this? Am I doing something wrong in my loop? 
I am working with Rails 3.1.3, Rake 0.9.2.2 and MySQL2 0.3.7

Comment: You might want to move your `part.title =~ REGEX` test into the database, doing `Model.all.each` usually ends up being a bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean by: move it into the database? I want to update each record with a field that matches my regex criteria

Comment: Query on that condition (`Part.where(...)`) and let the database handle that part, pulling the entire table into Ruby land and testing the records there isn't very nice.

Comment: And, depending on the database, you might be able to do the whole substitution inside the database without pulling any data into Ruby at all. That depends on the datZbase you're using and what your regex looks like though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because the way ActiveRecord detects that attributes are changed is through the setter.  Therefore, if you use `gsub!` on an attribute, ActiveRecord doesn't know it needs to update the database.

You'll probably have to do this:

```
part.title = part.title.gsub REGEX, '\2 \1'
```

### Update from comment

Also, if you try to assign title to another variable and then gsub! it won't work either because it's the same object (code from my project, variable names different).

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :020 > t = p.name
 => "test" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :023 > t.object_id
 => 70197586207500 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :024 > p.name.object_id
 => 70197586207500 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :025 > t.gsub! /test/, 'not a test'
 => "not a test" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :037 > p.name = t
 => "not a test" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :026 > p.save
   (37.9ms)  BEGIN
** NO CHANGES HERE **
   (23.9ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

You have to `.dup` the string before modifying it.

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :043 > t = p.name.dup
 => "test" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :044 > t.gsub! /test/, 'not a test'
 => "not a test" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :045 > p.name = t
 => "not a test" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :046 > p.save
   (21.5ms)  BEGIN
   (20.8ms)  UPDATE "projects" SET "name" = 'not a test', "updated_at" = '2012-01-02 07:17:22.892032' WHERE "projects"."id" = 108
   (21.5ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

Comment: I tried doing `text.gsub!` on a variable then setting `part.title = text` but that didnt work either

Comment: If you do that, then you have to `.dup` the variable before you do that.