# Unable to update database column value from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a modal in rails named Release and i want to update a single column value for a specific row from rails console, my Release modal is:

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :histories, dependent: :destroy
end
```

So first i open the rails console in production environment:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

than i find the specific row using row id:

```
r=Release.find(92)
```

than i update the value of a column of the above selected row:

```
x=r.reason
x.gsub!("abc","xyz")
r.reason=x
r.save!
```

all the above query run successfully. But when i check the value again it still shows the old value:

```
Release.find(92).reason
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, it's something related to `object_id`

You will have to do

```
x=r.reason.dup
```

Then it works fine.

**source:** [It's because the way ActiveRecord detects that attributes are changed is through the setter. Therefore, if you use gsub! on an attribute, ActiveRecord doesn't know it needs to update the database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698240/rake-rails-save-not-updating-database)

Edit: It has nothing related to DB type.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I think you could also write it more explicitly as follows:

```
r.update_attributes reason: r.reason.gsub!('abc','xyz')
```

Comment: update_attributes is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1